# Repaint small part of form only using Delphi?

Tags: delphi, redraw

In my program I have a custom `TPanel` that slides out from above and has buttons and images on it. It slides out fine but when I go to hide it, it is very slow. I have tried several methods and all are the same result. If you notice below I tried Redraw thinking I could just redraw the trailing rect but this call redraws the entire form as does all the other methods I have tried. I even tried using scroll. Am I calling it wrong or is there a better way to just update the form part that needs updating as the panel moves up?

```
while z>mypanels[panel].Fstarttop do
begin
   if z-x<mypanels[panel].Fstarttop then z:=mypanels[panel].Fstarttop else z:=z-x;
   updaterect:=Rect(mypanels[panel].left,z+mypanels[panel].height,mypanels[panel].left+mypanels[panel].width,mypanels[panel].top+mypanels[panel].height);
   mypanels[panel].top:=z;
   //mypanels[panel].Repaint;
   //Application.ProcessMessages;  
   //mypanels[panel].ScrollBy(0,-x);
   //InvalidateRect(form1.Handle,@updaterect,FALSE);
   //Application.ProcessMessages;
   //RedrawWindow(form1.Handle,@updaterect, 0, RDW_UPDATENOW);
   //form1.refresh;
end;
```

Comment: did you try InvalidateRect yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Moving a panel should not take long. Also, to update the parent of the panel, a call to `Form.Update` should be just fine. To force a redraw of only a portion of a form, a call to `InvalidateRect` should do, as you have already done (try clearing the background though).

Possible reasons for the delay and/or smudging are:

- you do some extensive own drawing in `Form.OnPaint`,
- `Anchors`, `Align`, and/or `Constraints` of panel and/or form are contradicting or result in a chain-reaction (in this case, try `DisableAlign` and `EnableAlign`),
- the form is not the immediate parent of the panel,
- the panel is over some other control,
- your `updaterect` variable is the new rectangle instead of the previous one,
- something else in your code and/or calling routine,
- any combination of the above.

Comment: Ended up going with: InvalidateRect(form1.Handle,@updaterect,FALSE);
                    form1.update;

Comment: I also removed the panel repaint as It wasnt needed. There were also several controls under the panel. These were minimized and the speed increased to an exceptible rate. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Another approach it to use windows update regions.
Your Tpanel as a "handle" property, that you can use with invalidateRect.

Normally the vcl will redraw :
- the background of your panel
- Only the controls in the invalidated rectangle

Comment: The panel paints fine. I use the panel.repaint call. If I only use that the panel goes up nice but leaves the trailing edge smeered on the main form below it. I just need to repaint the rect of the form that the panel no longer occupies. The updaterect part of the code. all the // marks show the different methods I have tried so far.

Comment: you'd better use panel.invalidate if there is no immediate need to iterrapt normal sequence and redraw right away

Comment: @user1704980 that is exactly what you've been told to do. VCL is simplified in that regard, it can only invalidate the whole TWinControl.
You should take Form.Handle, construct TRect with proper coordinates and use Win32 API InvalidateRect http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145005.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the parent TForm's DoubleBuffered property to True. This will help reduce the execution cost of redraws and may reduce the jitters of your close-up animation.

Comment: The forms doublebuffer is set to true already. In fact I even checked that everything that has that setting is set to true. The animation is smooth just really slow.